# Understanding mapStateToProps & mapDispatchToProps in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to understand the `connect()` method of **react-redux**. Usually it takes two function as argument: `mapStateToProps()` & `mapDispatchToProps()`. I write a example for myself, here is `connect()` section of my `User` component:

```
//imports...

class User extends Component {
    /* constructor, JSX, other functions... */
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   return {
     users: state.UserReducer
   };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  deleteUser: (id) => dispatch(deleteUser(id))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(User);
```

According to [Docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) I have taken the following two conclusions about `mapStateToProps()` & `mapDispatchToProps()`:

- **mapStateToProps()**: it makes that state available in our component. i.e. it is used to pass `reducer` to component.
- **mapDispatchToProps()**: it maps component relevant functions to `action` functions, i.e. with this function We can perform the `action` that we want in our `component`.

is my conclusions  correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React components accept data from outside via `props`.
`maptStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`, literally, pass the selected state properties and actions that are needed inside your component as props.
The state values and actions passed to the component are available in the props of the component.
In your example, you can use `this.props.users` or `this.props.deleteUser()`.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, what's your comment about my two conclusions (mark via bullet symbol in my question)?

Comment: you are welcome! actually i was not sure if you stated your thoughts correctly. it's correct that they are passing the state and actions to the component, but i think you are thinking that you can use the state and actions passed to the component as the properties of the component? like `this.deleteUser`?

Comment: I'm not thinking that, `deleteUser` is a function in my component that finally call `this.props.deleteUser(id);`